# Partial Derivatives - Chain Rule / Polar Coordinates Problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

(please see image link below) Currently stuck on this problem involving the chain rule and partial derivatives. Having looked at the highlighted part of the solution, I can't figure out two things:

- Surely the $\sin\psi$ term should be zero, as it's just taking the partial derivative with respect to $r$ of $\sin\psi$?
- Likewise, shouldn't the $r \cos\psi$ term be simply $\cos\psi$, as it's just the partial derivative of $\sin\psi$ with respect to $\psi$?

Any advice would be much appreciated. 
[image: partial derivative chain rule problem]

Comment: My immediate advice is to include critical parts of your question as text. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in question summaries. MathJax is used for formatting mathematical expressions here. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There’s a typo in the text: it should have $y=r\sin\psi$ instead of $y=\sin\psi$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).